# contextMenu for list view

Tags: android-layout, listview, contextmenu

i am using a list view. I use an adapter to add the items for this list. I am trying to add contextmenu for each item of the list but i have problems for this.

Here is my code

the item list :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bgActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorContact"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pick_options"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:text="@string/label_options" >
</Button>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

the list :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lst_contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bgContactItem" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The menu :

```
<menu 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/CtxLblOpc1" android:title="OpcEtiqueta1"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/CtxLblOpc2" android:title="OpcEtiqueta2"></item>
</menu>
```

java code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

// Getting reference to listview
    ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);
registerForContextMenu(lstContacts);
}

@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, 
                                    View v, 
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_options, menu);


}


/** Actions for the ContextMenu items */
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  //AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.CtxLblOpc1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                         "Option 1",     
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          return true;
      case R.id.CtxLblOpc2:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                         "Option 2", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          return true;
      default:
          return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

but i not see the contextmenu, please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try to add (in layout)

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in your layout.
You can give a look [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listviewarrayadapter-and.html)
I suggest you to use the context menu with ActionMode.Callback. If you want an example look [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-listview-context-menu.html)

*Note: Links are from my blog*